# phpDocumentor: DocBlock with @var tags duplicates descriptions

Tags: php, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

I have this DocBlock in a php abstract class:

```
/**
* @var string $foo a useful foo and <code>some.code()</code> too
* @var string $bar a useless bar
*
* @todo do something with <code>$this->bar</code>
*/
protected $foo, $bar;
```

I parsed this class with phpDocumentor; and here's the html result:
[image]

As you can see both `$foo` and `$bar` shares the same description (the $foo one) and markdown is not parsed too.
On the other hand markdown of `@todo` tag is properly parsed.

Where am I wrong?
Did I miss something?

I found a bug [ticket about markdown in `@var` tags](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/368):
Has it something to do with this issue maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always document above the var itself. Maybe that's the issue

```
/**
* @var string $foo a useful foo and <code>some.code()</code> too
*/
protected $foo;
/*
* @var string $bar a useless bar
*
* @todo do something with <code>$this->bar</code>
*/
protected $bar;
```

Comment: Thanks Machavity, it solved the first issue (descriptions now refer to the correct variables).
There are still two more things:
1) markdown still isn't parsed
2) in phpDocumentor's [documentation](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html) there's one example of a DocBlock with 2 `@var`, so maybe there is a way.